# Easiest way to play Super Mario World on Macbook laptop

Tags: emulation, backwards-compatibility, super-mario-world

I'd like to play Super Mario World (SNES Mario) on my Macbook laptop using a controller that's somewhat similar to the SNES controller.  **What's the easiest way to do this (Software, controllers etc)?**

Comment: Questions about piracy are off-topic as per our [FAQ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download a SNES emulator for the Mac OS edition [from here](http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Games/SNESX.shtml), then dump a Super Mario World ROM from your own cartridge.

In regards to the controller, you can buy one or use the keyboard.

Comment: Hey erdeni, welcome to the site! While discussing emulation is cool since it's not illegal, n the future, please don't link to ROM distribution sites or answer a question with "download a ROM from a site", as these are illegal activities. Since making your own personal private backup from a cartridge isn't technically illegal, I kept the part about dumping a ROM.